# How can I use cross-references and hyperlinks to parts of an align environment?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, amsmath, align

I'm writing an exercise book, and in some exercises I'll have several numbered equations in an align environment, e.g.,

(1) x^2+x+1=0,  (2) ax^3+2x=0,  (3) x^5=2i,

(4) x^4=-i, (5) x-1/x=2, (6) cosh(x)=3.

(I'll want them to be aligned with respect to the number).

I'm using a macro `\newcommand*\ExoEq{\refstepcounter{ExoEq}(\theExoEq)~}`

so that the previous example is typed as:

```
\begin{align*}
\ExoEq&x^2+x+1=0,&
\ExoEq&ax^3+2x=0,&
\ExoEq&x^5=2i,\\
\ExoEq&x^4=-i,&
\ExoEq&x-\frac1x=2,&
\ExoEq&\cosh(x)=3.
\end{align*}
```

All is good so far, except that I sometimes need to refer to an equation, e.g.,

```
In Equation~(2), we assume that $a\neq0$.
```

The thing is when I want to use `\label` and `\eqref`, I get weird results in the align environment: here is a minimal example that shows what goes wrong:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\parindent0pt

\newtheoremstyle{myexercise}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}{}{}{\bfseries}{.}{ }{\thmname{#1}\ \thmnumber{#2}}%
\theoremstyle{myexercise}
\newtheorem{Exo}{Exercise}[section]

\newcounter{MyCounter}
\newcommand*\Number{\refstepcounter{MyCounter}(\theMyCounter)~}

\let\oldlabel\label

\begin{document}
\section{Exercises}
\begin{Exo}
\begin{align*}
\Number\oldlabel{L1}&x^2+x=2,&
\Number\oldlabel{L2}&x^3+x^2=0.
\end{align*}
Equation~\eqref{L1} is very nice, and Equation~\eqref{L2}
is lovely too.
\end{Exo}
\end{document}
```

Without the hyperref package, I get the exercise reference, instead of the equation reference. With the hyperref package, I get an error on the second latex pass.

I'm using a `\let\oldlabel\label` trick, as the align* environment redefines `\label`, and it just doesn't work with `\label` instead.

How can I work around this annoying thing to have it work?

Comment: Since you don't align at relation symbols, I recommend to use a `tabular(x)` environment with equations in cells instead of `align`.

Answer (score 4):

### amsmath align fix

It works if you redefine `\eqref` to use the starred version `\ref*` which doesn't create a hyperlink:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref*{#1}}}}
\makeatother
```

### tabular solution

Though I recommend to use the numbered environment `align` instead of `align*`. I can see that you use `align*` to achieve an unusual numbering style. However, I would rethink if it's worth to differ from the common style.

As I said in my comment: since you don't align at relation symbols, I recommend to use a `tabular(x)` environment with equations in cells instead of `align`. Here's a quick example which uses you numbering macros:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
...
\begin{Exo}

\begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}{XX}
  \Number\label{L1} \(x^2+x=2\), &
  \Number\label{L2} \(x^3+x^2=0\). 
\end{tabularx}

Equation~\eqref{L1} is very nice, and Equation~\eqref{L2}
is lovely too.
\end{Exo}
```

[image]

You could take further care of spacing, centering and hyperlink design.

Morover, you could use numbered `equation` environments in tables if you use `\parbox` or `minipage` for those within cells. It requires to specify a width, but you could rely on LaTeX's resp. amsmath's numbering instead of on your self-made solution.

### enumerated list solution

A third way is to use an enumerated list. The look of the label can be changed to be like an equation tag with parentheses. For multicolum equations, which are horizontally numbered, you could use the [multenum](http://ctan.org/pkg/multenum) package.

A small example with your theorem environment, yet without referencing worked out:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multienum}
\renewcommand{\regularlisti}{\setcounter{multienumi}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\labelenumi}%
  {\addtocounter{multienumi}{1}(\arabic{multienumi})}}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\parindent0pt
\newtheoremstyle{myexercise}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}{}{}%
  {\bfseries}{.}{ }{\thmname{#1}\ \thmnumber{#2}}%
\theoremstyle{myexercise}
\newtheorem{Exo}{Exercise}[section]
\begin{document}
\section{Exercises}
\begin{Exo}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\begin{multienumerate}
  \mitemxx{\(x^2+x=2\),}{\(x^3+x^2=0\).} 
\end{multienumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{Exo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works with \ref*. However I have two issues with it: First, I'd like to keep a hyperlink, but this is a detail. When I compile, I get the error (\end occurred when \ifmmode on line 28 was incomplete). Now, I'm using align* and put several equations on one line, just to save space. It's an exercise book, and not a research article, so it doesn't matter if several equations are on one single line. My colleagues use a multi-column environment for this, but I don't like it, since equations are numbered downward. Anyways, I'm keeping your solution as a fallback.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: you could extend your macros by `hyperref` commands, such as `\hypertarget` and `\hyperref`.